# Replace a specific string on an HTML page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

We are supplying a blob of HTML content to be imported and displayed on someone else's page. The owners of the page put a title around our content blob, but the title is the name of our web service that provides the content, rather than a user-friendly name that we want to display to users. They can't figure out how to change the title on their end, we don't want to change the name of our web service, and it needs to look good for a demo in a few days.

The ideal solution would be for them to figure out how to use their portal tool to be able to customize titles, but that is not likely to happen before the demo. So I was thinking we could include some JavaScript in the content that we send them, which would change the title for them. This would buy them time to figure out what they are doing.

The code for their title looks like this:

```
<div class="titleClass"> Bad Title </div>
```

I would like to replace "Bad Title" with "Good Title". I would like to locate this text on the page using a jQuery selector, but unfortunately there are multiple div items with the class of titleClass and I only want to change one of them.... is there a selector I could use that would also check for the text "Bad Title" inside the div tag? Or do I have to write a separate function that would loop through all the different titles on the page, and test each one to see if it contains "Bad Title"? If I have to do the second, does anyone have sample code to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You want do it simplier?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('div.titleClass:contains("Bad Title")').text( "Good title" );
});
```

Look at the [contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) selector.

Comment: Won't do for an exact match, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

First get a collection of all the elements with matching text:

```
var $matches = $('div.titleClass').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Bad Title';
});
```

and then replace the text of the matching elements:

```
$matches.each(function() {
    $(this).text('New Title');
});
```

The above will look for elements with text *exactly matching* 'Bad Title'. If you want any element that *contains* the text 'Bad Title', e.g. 'A Bad Title', you should use `indexOf` or `search`, e.g.:

```
return $(this).text().indexOf('Bad Title') > -1;
```

One last caveat is case-sensitivity. If you want to do a case-insensitive match, I would suggest something like this:

```
// the div contains Bad Title of whatever case
return $(this).text().search(/Bad Title/i) > -1;

// the div exactly matches Bad Title of whatever case
return $(this).text().search(/Bad Title/i) > == 0;
```

Comment: @jitter - that depends on whether he wants the title to *contain* 'Bad Title' or *match* 'Bad Title'. I assumed the latter.

Comment: I'm actually glad to have both options. Thanks!

Comment: @jitter - I've re-edited to include your idea plus case-insensitive matching. Hopefully that covers most use cases.

Comment: jQuery makes people dumb and lazy, I swear.  This is what you are doing:  First you get all divs with the class of "titleClass".  Then you loop through them and remove the ones that don't have the right text.  Then you loop through them again and set the text.  There is *no* reason to loop twice here.