# Replace word with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have word Hello on most of my pages and i want to change it to Welcome.
Is it possible and if yes how to replace the words with jQuery?

```
Hello
<p>Hello user Jack</p>
<div>Hell ow you from us
    <h1>12344 Hello</h1>
    <div>Hellow</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Question already resolved. 

]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637269/replace-a-specific-string-on-an-html-page-using-jquery

Comment: @reggie, doesn't answer my question. I want to replace x word in all dom objects to word y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this snippet will do it:

```
$('body, body *')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
            && this.nodeValue.indexOf('Hello') >= 0;
    }).each(function() {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\bHello\b/g, 'Welcome');
    });
```

I really wouldn't recommend using it, but it's nice to know it's possible in a pinch.

It works by finding all the text nodes that have 'Hello' in them, then uses a regular expression to do a global replace on the word 'Hello' with 'Welcome' for each of those text nodes.

Comment: Your solution is works 95%, which is great but there is slight problem if Value like Hellow exists in some node it being replace to Welcomew when it needed to remain Hellow.

Comment: @Cameron, nice one there was an issue with Hello outside of any tag, just in body and i fixed it by modifying selector $('body,body *'). // Another small issue i have is that new regex does not recognize non English values. I guess there is some escape for non-unicode stuff

Comment: @eugeneK: What do you mean when you say the regex is not regognizing non-English values? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Cameron, in example Hebrew doesn't work with your regex. I did replace word Hello with שלום and Welcome with ברוך

Comment: @eugeneK: Aha, that's not at all like your original sample ;-) In the regex, I think you'll need to use the codepoint values (e.g. `/\b\ufeff\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd\b/`).

Answer (score 2):

Permanently?  You're better off just doing a search and replace across multiple files.

Comment: @eugeneK, in the 11 mins it took you to get this reply and reply back, you could have done dozens of these search and replaces, even manually..

Comment: @Blindy, i do that for a reason. Instead of telling me how it is wrong which i already states i know you could help me. Thanks anyway

Comment: Use Dreamweaver or any decent free text editor and you can search and replace across multiple files.  Should take you a minute to do.

Comment: cool i do that for a reason? Can you help me with jQuery or other JS method?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.title').html('Welcome');
});
```

I'm guessing here that it is in a tag, on its own. If you need more than that (Hello being part of a sentence) then you'll need to use something like $('.title').replace('Hello','Welcome')

Edit: This is my current train of thought, I'm a bit busy so I thought I would throw it down just in case you can slot the last piece in:

```
function scanReplace($element) {
    $element.children().each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text().replace('Hello','Welcome');
        if ( $this.children().length > 0 ) scanReplace($this);
    });
}

scanReplace($('body'));
```

Comment: I want it to replace x word with y word at any dom object

Comment: OK, Updated with a thought, it isn't complete but I've gotten busy. I'll keep trying to get an actual working solution soon but there is something to help you if you were totally stuck

Comment: @Dorjan, it doesn't work yet. Do children() iterate thought all dom elements inside of body ot just direct children? Does replace() with replace Hello with Welcome if the this DOM element have Hello user?

Comment: It's the replace failing. If you look at the debug info on the jquery you'll see that the body chldren looks at everything. So to get this working we just need to fix the replace statement I believe.

Comment: @Dorjan, i guess RegEx could fix this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the search to be much better (I think), just need to used regex instead of replace. Let know how you get on though.

Comment: I've added another answer below which pretty much does what we were trying to do here but with more time spent on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with the `.replace` function. Only the word that you want to replace has to be in a string.

```
var old_line = "Hello World!";
var new_line = old_line.replace('World', 'Stackoverflow');
```

You can also replace multi words like:

```
var old_line = "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!";
var new_line = old_line.replace(/World/gi, 'Stackoverflow');
alert(new_line); //Output: Hello Stackoverflow! Hello Stackoverflow! Hello Stackoverflow! Hello Stackoverflow!
```

Comment: I want it to replace x word with y word at any dom object

Answer (score 1):

I used the below snippet

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(old_word, new_word));
```

with $(this) being the object containing the text you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

Might've found something which would be better than our hacked attempted above.

Have a look :)

edit: here is its working page: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/examples/replacetext/

Apparently they went down the same route as us but have spent more time on it and it's well, complete :D